# In flask, how to route a link generated by OAuth 2?

Tags: python, oauth, flask

I'm building a web app with flask. I used

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    .....
    return render_template('home.html',url=url)
```

to generate the index page. There is a link(the second parameter, url) on the index page which leads to weibo (the chinese "twitter") for OAuth 2. After clicking the link and inputing the weibo username and password, I'm bounced back to a link like `www.myflaskwebappaddress.com/?code=valueofcode`.

My question is how can I catch the value of code and do something with the code in another page.

I tried the following:

```
@app.route(url_for('/', code=<tokencode>))  
def show_data(tokencode):
     .....want to use weibo api here using the tokencode.
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything after the `?` is a *query parameter*; Flask parses those and provides them as part of the [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) object:

```
@app.route(url_for('/')  
def home():
    tokencode = request.args.get('code')
    if tokencode is not None:
        # there was a `?code=...` query parameter.
```

Also see [*The Request Object*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object) in the Flask quickstart.

Routing is only dependent on the path and the method of the request, the parameters don't play in that, so you *cannot* create a separate route for requests with that parameter.

You could, instead, use a [`before_request` handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/?highlight=before_request#callbacks-and-errors) to look out for the code:

```
@app.before_request
def check_token():
    tokencode = request.args.get('code')
    if tokencode is not None:
        # there was a `?code=...` query parameter.
```

If this function returns `None`, the normal routing takes place. But you can also return valid response; in that case that is the response returned to the end user and normal routing is skipped entirely.

This also means you can use *any* route on your site with a `?code=<tokencode>` query parameter and have the `before_request` hook function handle it, not just your homepage.

Comment: Thanks a lot~! The "request.arg" method solved my problem. before_request handler looks powerful, but I'm not sure how to pass the parameter to a future page it directs to yet. Maybe session or cookie should do.

Comment: I don't know what you wanted to achieve here, but a Flask session does let you remember values per visitor, yes, without having to add query parameters to every URL.